# Hubot makefile test task not working

Tags: makefile, coffeescript, hubot

I get this when I run make test:

```
coffee test/my_script_test.coffee
xargs: coffee: No such file or directory
make: *** [test] Error 127
```

My makefile is unaltered from this https://github.com/github/hubot-scripts/blob/master/Makefile

I can run hubot perfectly, so I am not sure why xargs is disliking coffee.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have CoffeeScript installed? Is there a `coffee` command in your `PATH`? What happens if you `which coffee` from the shell?

Comment: yes, no, and no. Should I add coffee into PATH in the Makefile?

Comment: Either add the directory for `coffee` to your `PATH` or edit the `Makefile` to include the full path to `coffee`.

Comment: I added the full path and it works now, thanks

Comment: Getting the makefile working lead me to discover that there is a hubot/node_modules/hubot folder with an already working makefile. Is that where I am supposed to put my scripts and tests?

I guess my real problem is that the hubot wiki is not very good and I can't find a good walkthrough that covers the dumb stuff that isn't obvious to beginners like where do you put files.